# angular2 uploading file to PHP, $_FILES is empty

Tags: php, angular

I am trying to upload files using angular2 and PHP server. The variable $_FILES is empty and I cannot figure out the reason.

Component code:
let formData:FormData = new FormData();

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.filmsFiles.length; i++) {
    formData.append('images', this.filmsFiles[i], this.filmsFiles[i].name);
}


this.filmDataService.uploadFiles(formData).subscribe( outPutData => {
  if(outPutData[0]){...
```

Service Angular code:

uploadFiles(formData:FormData): Observable {
    this.data = 'action=10060&jsonData=""';

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=' + Math.random().toString().substr(2));
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

return this.http.post(this.url+'?'+this.data, formData, options)
        .map((response:Response) => response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError)
```

}

PHP code:

```
foreach($_FILES['images']['error'] as $key => $error){
        if($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
            $name = $_FILES['images']['name'][$key];
            $fileNameParts = explode(".", $name);
            $nameWithoutExtension = $fileNameParts[0];
            $extension = end($fileNameParts);
            $newFileName = "film_".$i.time().".".$extension;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key], '../../images/' . $newFileName);

            $newFileNames[]='images/filmsImages/'.$newFileName;
            $i++;
        }
```

I've been checking whether the variable this.filmsFiles is empty or not and it contains the files to upload, in the view, file tag, I have:

(change)="filmsFiles[i]=$event.target.files[0]"

The server receives the parameters I send but nothing in $_FILES.

Could you help me please?

Thanks,
Roberto

Comment: Did you try removing the content-type headers?  I recall having issues with manually setting those before.

Comment: The headers I use are: headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; charset=utf-8; boundary=' + Math.random().toString().substr(2));
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json'); That's what I was told to use.

Comment: I've finally figured out what happened. As you said I had to remove the headers and the code is: "let headers = new Headers();
    
    return this.http.post(this.url+'?'+this.data, formData, { headers })
            .map((response:Response) => response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError)" Thanks!!

Comment: Just one more thing. The document is reloaded after the files uploading and I do not understand why, no actions are executed after uploading. Could you help me please? Thanks again!

Comment: By document, do you mean the page?  So, you click submit and the http post occurs, and then the page refreshes?  My initial guess is that there is a default form post action occurring.  If the submit button is used for the click event for your http post method, then ensure that you're doing an `event.preventDefault()` on it, or the page will appear to reload as a normal form submission.

Comment: Yes, by document I mean page. And you've understood my issue perfectly. The refresh happens only if I upload the files, by commenting the uploading, I execute an insert in database, which is executed and no refresh is applied. If I execute both, uploading files and database insert, the page refreshes. I've tried the sentence event.preventDefault() once both actions are executed but the page refreshes anyway. Do you know why? Thanks!